# Rendering Image with ReactJS received from flask-restful API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, flask-restful

I'm sending an image with flask-restful but I can't render it using ReactJS. I tried to use btoa and blob to solve the issue but with no results. here is the code I wrote

The flask-restful code:

```
class UploadImage(Resource):
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'img'
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('file', 
          type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
    location='files',
    required=True, help='Must provide username')

def post(self):
    data = self.parser.parse_args()
    if data['file'] == "":
        return {
            'data':'',
            'message': 'No File Found',
            'status': 'Error'
        }
    photo = data['file']

    if photo:
        filename = 'input.png'
        path = os.path.join(self.UPLOAD_FOLDER,filename)
        photo.save(path)
    # with open(path, "rb") as f:
    #     encoded_image = f.read()
    #     print(type(encoded_image))
        return send_file(path, mimetype='image/png')
```

The React code:

```
onButtonClick = () => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', this.state.image, this.state.image.name)

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/image', fd).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        features: res.data
      })

    })
  }
render() {
    const { features } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
        type='file'
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Upload</button>
        <br />
        {features && <img src={features} alt='some text'/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem thank you.

Comment: can you `console.log(res.data)`?

Comment: yes of course, check the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs1uv52dwbd4a9p/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202018-05-12%20%C3%A0%2018.09.36.png?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried `res.blob()`?

Comment: yes the problem bellow occurs: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.blob is not a function

Comment: What if you change the server `post` function to return the path instead of image? Then in your component just give the path to `<img>` `src`.

Comment: If you have a way I'll be happy to learn it. thank you